# SQL First Time In Last Time Out (Transact-SQL..preferrably)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table which contains all the time in and time out of people:

```
 CREATE TABLE test (
       timecardid INT
     , trandate DATE
     , employeeid INT
     , trantime TIME
     , Trantype VARCHAR(1)
     , Projcode VARCHAR(3)
)
```

The task is to get all the earliest trantime with trantype A (perhaps using MIN) and the latest trantime with trantype Z (Using Max), all of which in that trandate (ie. trantype A for july 17 is 8:00 AM and trantype Z for july 17 is 7:00PM).

the problem is, the output should be in the same format as the table where it's coming from, meaning that I have to leave this data and filter out the rest (that aren't the earliest and latest in/out for that date, per employee)

My current solution is to use two different select commands to get all earliest, then get all the latest. then combine them both.

I was wondering though, is there a much simpler, single string solution?

Thank you very much.

EDIT (I apologize, here is the sample. Server is SQL Server 2008):

```
 Timecardid | Trandate | employeeid | trantime | trantype | Projcode 
      1      2013-04-01      1        8:00:00        A       SAMPLE1
      2      2013-04-01      1        9:00:00        A       SAMPLE1
      3      2013-04-01      2        7:00:00        A       SAMPLE1
      4      2013-04-01      2        6:59:59        A       SAMPLE1
      5      2013-04-01      1       17:00:00        Z       SAMPLE1
      6      2013-04-01      1       17:19:00        Z       SAMPLE1
      7      2013-04-01      2        17:00:00       Z       SAMPLE1

      8      2013-04-02      1        8:00:00        A       SAMPLE1
      9      2013-04-02      1        9:00:00        A       SAMPLE1
     10      2013-04-02      2        7:00:58        A       SAMPLE1
     11      2013-04-02      2       18:00:00        Z       SAMPLE1
     12      2013-04-02      2       18:00:01        Z       SAMPLE1
     13      2013-04-02      1       20:00:00        Z       SAMPLE1
```

Expected Results (the earliest in and the latest out per day, per employee, in a select command):

```
  Timecardid | Trandate | employeeid | trantime | trantype | Projcode 
      1      2013-04-01      1        8:00:00        A       SAMPLE1 
      4      2013-04-01      2        6:59:59        A       SAMPLE1   
      6      2013-04-01      1       17:19:00        Z       SAMPLE1
      7      2013-04-01      2        17:00:00       Z       SAMPLE1
      8      2013-04-02      1        8:00:00        A       SAMPLE1
     10      2013-04-02      2        7:00:58        A       SAMPLE1
     12      2013-04-02      2       18:00:01        Z       SAMPLE1
     13      2013-04-02      1       20:00:00        Z       SAMPLE1
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would add a lot to this question

Comment: Version of SQL server would also be helpful.

Comment: I apologize. Here is the edited results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
select 
    t.* 
from 
    test t
where 
    trantime in (
        (select min(trantime) from test t1 where t1.trandate = t.trandate and trantype = 'A'),
        (select max(trantime) from test t2 where t2.trandate = t.trandate and trantype = 'Z')
    )
```

Changing my answer to account for the "per employee" requirement:

```
;WITH EarliestIn AS
(
    SELECT trandate, employeeid, min(trantime) AS EarliestTimeIn
    FROM test 
    WHERE trantype = 'A'
    GROUP BY trandate, employeeid 
), 
LatestOut AS
(
    SELECT trandate, employeeid, max(trantime) AS LatestTimeOut
    FROM test 
    WHERE trantype = 'Z'
    GROUP BY trandate, employeeid 
)
SELECT * 
FROM test t
WHERE 
    EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EarliestIn WHERE t.trandate = EarliestIn.trandate AND t.employeeid = EarliestIn.employeeid AND t.trantime = EarliestIn.EarliestTimeIn) 
    OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM LatestOut WHERE t.trandate = LatestOut.trandate AND t.employeeid = LatestOut.employeeid AND t.trantime = LatestOut.LatestTimeOut)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming timecardid column is PK or unique, and if I understand it correctly, I would do something like

```
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = '2013-07-01'

SELECT
    T0.*
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT employeeid FROM test) E
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            T.timecardid
        FROM
            test T
        WHERE
            T.trandate = @date
            AND T.Trantype = 'A'
            AND T.employeeid = E.employeeid
        ORDER BY T.trantime
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOP 1
            T.timecardid
        FROM
            test T
        WHERE
            T.trandate = @date
            AND T.Trantype = 'Z'
            AND T.employeeid = E.employeeid
        ORDER BY T.trantime DESC
    ) V
    JOIN test T0 ON T0.timecardid = V.timecardid
```

Appropriate indexes should be set for the table, if you aware of performance.

Comment: I meant that, as far as I remember, type DATE was introduced only in SQL Server 2008. Keep in mind compatibility if your development environment is 2008 or later and production can be SQL Server 2005.

Comment: there is a type DATE. I apologize I'm actually using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to sort out the rows you want to select:

```
;with Ordered as (
  select *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Trandate,employeeid,trantype
        ORDER BY trantime ASC) as rnEarly,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Trandate,employeeid,trantype
        ORDER BY trantime DESC) as rnLate
  from
    Test
)
select * from Ordered
where
  (rnEarly = 1 and trantype='A') or
  (rnLate = 1 and trantype='Z')
order by TimecardId
```

([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/071a7/2))

It produces the results you've requested, and I think it's quite readable. The reason that `trantype` is included in the `PARTITION BY` clauses is so that `A` and `Z` values receive separate numbering.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL server 2012, you can use LAG/LEAD to find the max and min rows in a fairly concise way;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
       LAG(timecardid)  OVER (PARTITION BY trandate,employeeid,trantype ORDER BY trantime)  lagid,
       LEAD(timecardid) OVER (PARTITION BY trandate,employeeid,trantype ORDER BY trantime) leadid
  FROM test
)
SELECT timecardid,trandate,employeeid,trantime,trantype,projcode
FROM cte
WHERE trantype='A' AND lagid  IS NULL
   OR trantype='Z' AND leadid IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9622d/1).

Comment: Questions:
-what exactly is lag/lead for?
-is LAG/LEAD only for SQL 2012?

Comment: @Malky.Kid LAG is the previous row in sort order, LEAD is the next row in sort order. The row where LAG is NULL for example is the row that has no previous row (ie the first one) LAG/LEAD are indeed SQL server 2012 only.

Comment: seems useful, what I do to get a previous row is that I have an int key field and use select-where key=item-1.